# Python pandas how to merge multiple row into one?

Tags: python, pandas

I have A dataframe as below:

```
Car        SeriesNo     White       Red        Black
Proton     A111           2       
Proton     A111                      4
Proton     A111                                  5
```

My Expected output will be:

```
Car        SeriesNo     White       Red        Black
Proton     A111           2          4           5
```

Anyone have ideas on this?

Comment: There are multiple groups by first 2 columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for get first non missing values per groups:

```
#if necessary replace empty strings to missing values
#df = df.replace('',np.nan)
df = df.groupby(['Car','SeriesNo'], as_index=False).first()
print (df)
      Car SeriesNo  White  Red  Black
0  Proton     A111    2.0  4.0    5.0
```

Comment: Interesting use of `groupby` here. Nice answer as always, much better than mine :)

Comment: @Chris - It depends what OP need, but I guess there are multiple groups, so then `groupby` here is necessary.